# Setting Width For Dojo Button

Tags: javascript, css, dojo

Note: It is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6057236/).

I am trying to create a dojo button programmatically like this:

```js
var btnOK = new dijit.form.Button({
    label: "OK",
    showLabel: true,
    style: "height: 20px; width: 50px;"
});
```

Now even though I specify the width, while displaying the button width is set to minimum (i.e text + margin). The reason as explained in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6057236/#6069457)  is that dojo overrides css style for button (`class="dijitButtonNode"`). Further (in the same answer) the width is set by overriding styles for same class.

Is it possible to do same (i.e set the width) without this css workaround ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally, I worked it out. To set the width we have to set width using dojo.style function

```
    dojo.create("button",{id: "btnOK",type: "button"},dojo.body());

    var btnOK = new dijit.form.Button({
                label: "OK",
                showLabel: true,
                style: "height: 20px;"
                },
               "btnOK");

    dojo.style("btnOK","width","40px");
```

Comment: You can accept your own answer when you solve things by yourself - helps get it out of the unsoved queue.

Answer (score 3):

Worked for me:

```
    domStyle.set(btnOk.domNode, "width", "100px");
    domStyle.set(btnOk.domNode.firstChild, "display", "block");
```

Comment: You can improve your answer by providing some context -- why does this work? Is there a reference document?

Comment: above codes worked, but how to set the height? domstyle.set(btnOk.domNode, "height", "30px") didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is to add a class to the button:

```
<input type="button" data-dojo-props="label : 'Test'" class="normalButton" id="test" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" />
```

In your CSS:

```
.normalButton span{
    width: 100px;
}
```

Extra: if you add this class your alignment of the text will be messed up. This can be solved by adding following CSS rules:

```
.{your theme: eg. tundra} .dijitButtonText{
    padding: 0;
}
```

Finally, check out [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GuyT/kbhsv854/).

Answer (score 0):

Full width button: https://jsfiddle.net/51jzyam7/

HTML:

```
<body class="claro">
    <button id="myButtonNode" type="button"></button>
</body>
```

JS:

```
require(["dijit/form/Button", "dojo/dom", "dojo/domReady!"], 
    function(Button, dom){
    var myButton = new Button({
    label: "My big button",
    class: 'myCSSClass',
}, "myButtonNode").startup();
});
```

CSS:

```
.dijitButton.myCSSClass{
    display: block;
 }
.dijitButton.myCSSClass .dijitButtonNode{
    width:100%;
}
```